# sqlalchemy, specify database name with DSN

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server from Linux using `sqlalchemy`. [This page](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#dsn-connections) shows DSN-based connection as below.

`engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@some_dsn")`

Is there a way to specify a database name using DSN? I am aware that we can specify a database name either in `odbc.ini` or a SQL query but I would like to know if we can also do something like this.

`engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@some_dsn/databasename")`

Comment: Have you tried just doing `engine.execute("USE databasename")` immediately after calling `engine_create` using the normal DSN syntax?

Comment: Oh wow this is great! I did not think of using SQL for this. Would you please turn this as an "answer" not "comment" so that I can choose this as a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass arguments directly to the pyodbc.connect method through the connect_args parameter in create_engine:

```
def my_create_engine(mydsn, mydatabase, **kwargs):
    connection_string = 'mssql+pyodbc://@%s' % mydsn
    cargs = {'database': mydatabase}
    cargs.update(**kwargs)
    e = sqla.create_engine(connection_string, connect_args=cargs)
    return e
```

This will also enable the database to be persisted through several transactions / sessions.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried something like this and it seemed to work fine

```python
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@some_dsn")
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute("USE databasename")
```

As a general rule we should be careful about changing the current catalog (a.k.a. "database") after establishing a connection because some technologies (e.g., JDBC `Connection` objects) keep track of the current catalog and can get confused if we directly call `USE ...` in T-SQL to change the current catalog. However, I'm not aware that pyodbc's `Connection` object does any such caching so this approach is probably okay.